# Jquery ajax is not working properly on android phone

Tags: android, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with Jquery ajax on Android. On computers ajax working
just fine, however on mobile (android) it is not working properly. On mobile shows
previous selected data.
This my js script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#team').click(function(){
        var team = $("#team").val(); 
   $.ajax
    ({
            type: "POST",
        url: base_url +'controller/function',
        cache: false,
        data: {'team': team},
        success: function(data) {
           $("#output").html(data);
      },
          error:function(){
      $("#output").html('error.');
         }   
    });
});  });
```

Let's say I have the following data:
a = 1, b=2, c=3, d=4.
If I select letter it should output accordingly digit. So,page is loaded on phone,
I select letter a, but nothing happens, then I select letter b and output is 1,
but it should be 2, then I select letter d, output is 2, but it should be 4, and so on. Always output
previous data and always first time nothing happens.
Any ideas? Is somebody had same problem?
May help: site based on codeigniter; tested on couple different mobiles, did not tested on windows or iphone phones.

Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried a sync call? I mean, setting the async value to false http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . maybe the requests just overlap.

Comment: @eduyayo thank you for your comment :) do you mean in script add this `async: false`? if yes, did not helped..

Comment: have u added a breakpoint in the server side and see whether the "function" is executed or not? I´m just discarding things

Comment: @eduyayo, I did not, the right function is executed..

Comment: Just for the shake of it and thinking about kind of weird behaviour with closures. Could you try using this?: `data: {'team': $("#team").val()},`

Comment: And rename the data in the parameter of the return function to another rhing whatever the thing

Comment: @eduyayo, thank you for trying to help. Did, what you asked and now it is not working, I renamed to `data1`. any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. Just changed `click` event to `change` event and now it is working properly on mobiles.
I hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the URL is correct?

Comment: what do you mean? on computer same script working properly, is there any differences on mobile?

Comment: Oh ok. There is no difference on mobile it should work.